# Calculate Compounding Interest Rate From Total Interest Rate?

Tags: finance

I would like to be able to calculate the interest rate that is compounded for a given total interest rate, and number of compounding events.

TotalInterestRate = ((1+CompoundingRate/#CompoundingEvents)^#CompoundingEvents)-1

Basically would like to solve this equation for Compounding Rate.

For a more concrete example, calculating the Monthly Interest Rate from a given APY.  The formula for APY given a Monthly Interest Rate would then be.

APY = ((1+InterestRate/12)^12)-1

What would be a good way to go about solving this equation?

Answer (score 1):

If we refer to the effective interest rate as $r$ (what you call the total interest rate) and we refer to the nominal interest rate as $n$ (what you call the compounding rate) and the compounding frequency as $N$, the formula you have is 
$$r=\left(1+\frac{n}{N}\right)^N-1$$ To solve for $n$:

$$\begin{align}
r+1 &=\left(1+\frac{n}{N}\right)^N\\
\sqrt[N]{r+1}&=1+\frac{n}{N}\\
\sqrt[N]{r+1}-1&=\frac{n}{N}\\
N\left(\sqrt[N]{r+1}-1\right)&=n\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Same, but using the symbols in the question: $\mbox{InterestRate} = 12(\sqrt[12]{\mbox{APY}+1}-1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I believe that is for a more specific example than the OP firsts asks about.

Comment: You are correct, I missed that...

Comment: +1 for unintentionally reminding me that "effective" and "real" interest rates are not the same thing.