# 2016-2022 inflation. Mismatch using CPI and percentage multiplication

Tags: statistics, percentages

*** sorry for double question *** Please, i'm going crazy :) This is my problem and i hope you can help me. I need to calculate total inflation for the period 2016-2022 in a certain coutry. The problem is that I can't match the data, obtaining the same result using the consumer price index and the annual percentage change. Data:

CPI

2015 ...... 100,0

2016 ...... 99,9

2017 ...... 101,3

2018 ...... 102,5

2019 ...... 103,2

2020 ...... 103,0

2021 ...... 105,0

2022 ...... 114,2

I'm using that formula: (CPI 2022 - CPI 2016) / CPI 2016 x 100. The result is: 14,314%. Is that correct?

Now, I want to obtain the same result only using the annual percentage change (assuming that the consumer price index is not available):

2015 ...... 100,0

2016 ...... 99,9 ...... -0,100%

2017 ...... 101,3 ...... 1,401%

2018 ...... 102,5 ...... 1,185%

2019 ...... 103,2 ...... 0,683%

2020 ...... 103,0 ...... -0,194%

2021 ...... 105,0 ...... 1,942%

2022 ...... 114,2 ...... 8,762%

I have tried to multiplicate percentages but doing this the result is 14.2%.
Doing other examples the gap seems relevant.

Also consider this case (same years 2016-2022)

LCI - Labour cost index

2015 ...... 92,7

2016 ......92,3

2017 ......93,1

2018 ......94,9

2019 ......96,4

2020 ......100,0

2021 ......99,3

2022 ......101,9

Percentages:

2015 ......92,7

2016 ......92,3...... -0,431%

2017 ......93,1...... 0,867%

2018 ......94,9...... 1,933%

2019 ......96,4 ...... 1,581%

2020 ......100,0 ...... 3,734%

2021 ......99,3 ...... -0,700%

2022 ......101,9..... 2,618%

Result using LCI: 10,401%

Result using percentages multipliation : 9,54%

Is that right? Why?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Comment: i'm sorry. I thought I missed some crucial data and it wouldn't let me delete the other one

Comment: Maybe it's because you have multiple answers? BTW please don't use the answer section to ask follow-up questions since that's not what they are for. I recommend deleting the self-answer to your original question since it seems like you copy-pasted it over here.

Comment: ok, I didn't do it intentionally. I hope to find an answer to this question :)

Comment: Here is a [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question better (mostly consists of putting numbers in between dollar signs, \$20\$ -> $20$). Also, try to use tables in markdown (click on the question mark when you edit your question) to better format your numbers.

Comment: In one set of numbers, you are including the result from 2016, and in the other, you are not.  If your CPI numbers are year-end values for the year in question and you want the CPI from the beginning of 2016 to the end of 2022, you need to use the year-end 2015 value to capture the 2016 inflation.

Comment: so should I use the 2015 CPI to include 2016 in the calculation?
Thanks!
My problem is knowing the overall inflation between 2016 and 2022 in that country.
Or in this case I shouldn't consider the first percentage of the series?
I'm trying to understand, I don't know if I've made myself clear

Comment: Try an example with two years only and you will immediately see what start and end CPIs you should use. An absolute no brainer.

Comment: @user317176's comment deals with it.  If you want the change from 201**6** to 2022 then you should not be multiplying by $(1-0.00100)$ in the CPI case or by $(1-0.00431)$ in the LCI case as those are the changes before the period you are interested in

Comment: Just a side note : The current inflation in Germany is $10$% , bot not per year , it is $10$% per month !

Comment: Thank you! In one set of numbers, I was including the result from 2016, and in the other, I was not.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at $99.9$ in 2016, eventually we landed at $114.2$ in 2022. Therefore, the currency inflated $\frac{114.2 - 99.9}{99.9} = 143/999 \approx 14.3\%$ from 2016 to 2022.

Comment: You can then use this to calculate exactly the specific format you need, for example the yearly rate so that compound over the years long period 2016 to 2019 equals 14.3. I'll let you refer to the rest of the examples on here for that, as otherwise I would be writing duplicate answers.

Comment: Thank you. But why not using CPI but percentages we don't obtain the same result? In the second example the gap is more relevant. 
In one of the comments above a user wrote that there is probably a problem in the years taken as reference. it's possible?

Comment: For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167332/calculate-compounding-interest-rate-from-total-interest-rate

Comment: For any two points of time, you can calculate the inflation of the currency over that specific interval of time.. But the total inflation between points in time $t1$ and $t2$ are assuming only information from that interval, it makes sense to compute solely based off the valuations at $t1$ and $t2$ using a difference formula, no? Are you trying to take small comparisons and use that to generate a single percentage somehow, like the difference between displacement and distance in physics?

Comment: If your question is how to interpret what differences between CPI and LCI mean economically , this is not the right stack exchange to ask that question.

Comment: I thought that since they were index numbers the calculation method was the same.
I know that the best method is to use the formula (CPI 2022-CPI 2016)/CPI 2016 x 100 or, in the second case (LCI 2022-LCI 2016)/LCI 2016 x 100). But why doesn't the same result come from using annual percentage changes? In the second example the gap is more evident (10,4% vs 9,5%...)
Apart from this, my problem is that, for a certain country, I do not have the CPI (IPCA-NEI) available but only the percentages from year to year, so I cannot calculate the total inflation between 2016 and 2022 by that index

Comment: Th actual product of difference percentages is 10.401%. Your percentages are not accurate enough and losing precision in the multiplication steps. Also, you'll get closer to 10.401% if you multiply $\exp(\text{$i$th difference%})$ instead of $(1+\text{$i$th difference%})$

Comment: mate, thank you for your patience :) I don't have that advanced knowledge. What do you mean with exp(ith difference%) instead of (1+ith difference%)? Thanks in advance

Comment: As in, $e^{-0.00431+0.00867+\cdots}$

Comment: versus $(1-0.00431)(1+0.00867)\cdots$